# Где хранится ключ SSH в OS X после удаления самого файла ключа?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

Добрый день!

Сгенерировал ключ c паролем через терминал. Получил 2 файла в папке ~/.ssh: id_rsa и id_rsa_pub.

После этого подключился к серверу (через терминал) с помощью данного ключа и пароля к нему. В папке ~/.ssh появился еще один файл known_hosts

Вопрос: после того, как я удаляю из папки все файлы доступ к серверу через терминал все равно сохраняется. Смотрел в связке ключей, там ничего не сохранено. Где же тогда хранится ключ? Допустим, я хочу убрать доступ у этого компьютера. Повторю удаление самих файлов ключей из папки ~/.ssh не помогает. Доступ все равно сохраняется и уже никакие ключи не требуются.

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

процессу, запущенному программой *ssh*, секретная часть ключа (обычно хранится в файле с именем `~/.ssh/id_rsa`) требуется лишь при установке соединения — для аутентификации и для [генерации сеансового ключа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH#%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5), которым в дальнейшем и шифруется трафик.

после установки соединения секретная часть ключа уже не требуется. она не сохраняется даже в памяти процесса *ssh*.

а сеансовый ключ хранится лишь в памяти процесса: он теряет смысл по окончании сессии (которая, естественно, заканчивается при завершении работы процесса *ssh*).

---

ах, да, процесс *ssh-agent* [хранит секретные ключи непосредственно в своей памяти](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39837/80778). раз вы про не упоминаете про эту программу, значит добавление ключей производится процессом *ssh* автоматически, благодаря наличию опции `addkeystoagent=yes` (см. `man ssh_config`) либо в одном из конфигурационных файлов, учитываемых процессом *ssh*, либо, как умолчание, благодаря услужливости того, кто компилировал для вас программу *ssh*.

посмотреть список ключей, хранимых в данный момент в памяти процессом *ssh-agent* для вашей учётной записи, можно, передав программе опцию `-l`:

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь все понятно. В памяти хранится 3 ключа. Вопрос как удалить их или как удалить какой-то 1 конкретный?

Comment: 1. `$ man ssh-add`. 2. `$ ssh-add -d ...` или `$ ssh-add -D`