# Добавление ssh ключа для git

Tags: linux, git, ssh, хостинг

Разместил на хостинге сайт. Проект лежит в приватном репозитории на github. Проблема в следующем: пока я не выполню эти две команды eval `ssh-agent` и `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` нельзя выполнить git pull (пишет `fatal: Could not read from remote repository`), но после каждого переподключения к хостингу мне приходится заново вбивать эти команды. Почему так происходит??

Comment: Думаю, проблема с SSH. Покажите конфиги ssh: `cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config` а также `cat ~/.ssh/config`. И покажите `git remote -v`. Или включите [дебаг](https://askubuntu.com/a/620985/932746) и туда упадет ошибка.

Comment: @TotalPusher вот конфиг: https://pastebin.com/LfhQhNPe Локального не было

Comment: 1. по поводу ssh-agent: прочитайте [два абзаца, начиная с «в современных версиях»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469423/178576). 2. по поводу необходимости [добавления ключа ssh-agent-у](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/815853/178576).

Comment: Судя по конфигу, файл `~/.ssh/id_rsa` цепляться должен. Что выводит `git config core.sshCommand "ssh -vvv"` и затем `git pull` ?

Comment: А вы приватный ключ держите на хостинге?! О_о... Почитайте про форвардинг локального агента, и забудьте держать приватные ключи на любых компьютерах, кроме **персонального**.

Comment: @0andriy на гитхабе есть деплой ключик, он какраз для таких целей.

Comment: @eri, GH учит плохому...

Comment: @0andriy да нет, там доступ к репе ридонли и ключик можно сделать отдельный для каждого сервера

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте права на папку `~/.ssh` должно 700 и принадлежать пользователю.