# Ssh не запрашивает пароль

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, password

Была установка пароля через `ssh-keygen -p` на приватный ключ. Но ssh по прежнему не спрашивает пароль при входе или в действиях с гитом. Что не так?

Comment: видимо, ключ уже расшифрован ssh-agent-ом.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да, точно. была очистка ключей, но агент снова добавляет этот ключ. может вы сталкивались с этим?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/815853/178576

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо за ваш ответ, но проблема все еще сохраняется. нигде в конфигах не прописана опция addkeystoagent и после удаления, все так же добавляется ключ. есть другие идеи?